# почему не считает сумму элементов от 1 до n?

Tags: pascal

```
program lb3_3_2;
uses crt;
var
  i, n: integer;
  sum: real;
begin
  writeln('Введите n');
  readln(n);
  sum := 0;
  i := 1;
  while i <= n do
  begin
    sum := sum + i;
    writeln('Сумма от 1 до n равна: ', sum);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: А что считает? Как должен остановиться Ваш цикл, если ни `i`, ни `n` не меняются?

Answer (score 1):

Вы нигде не увеличиваете `i`. Следовательно ваш код никогда не выйдет из цикла `while` и будет бесконечно выводит всё возрастающие числа, т.к. вывод у вас тоже внутри цикла.

Попробуйте исправить эти 2 ошибки - увелчивайте `i` и выводите на экран результат по выходу из цикла, вот так:

```
while i<=n do
begin
    sum:=sum+i;
    i := i + 1;
end;

writeln('Сумма от 1 до n равна: ',sum);
```